# How do you train Google Speech-to-text to recognize foreign names

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

I'm summarizing some texts that I'm reading in Irish mythology but Google's Speech-to-text API cannot recognize the foreign words.  So names like: 'Diarmud', 'Grannie', 'geasa', 'gilla', 'decaire', 'Oisin' are not getting transcribed correctly.  Of course, there is an easy work around: just say some other word then program the computer to always replace those words with their Irish counterparts.  Still, I would like to know if there is a better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the below link, you might find something useful

[Speech Adaption Boost](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/boost)

This allows you to write some phrases and it's boost value(occurance value) so the API will give more weightage and priority to those words written in the phrases based on its boost values.